# how to use C# script in HEAT Harvest

Tags: c#, wix

I have a wix project, and I want to use the C# code in xslt file like this:

```xml
    ....
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component/@Guid">
        <xsl:attribute name="Guid">
            <xsl:value-of select="csharp:NewGuid()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="csharp">
        <![CDATA[
        public static string NewGuid()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

but when I build the project, I got this error:
`Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it.`

I do some search in official documents and tried to use `HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids` and `HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow` in wixproj file, like this:

```xml
    <HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>true</HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>
    <HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow>true</HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow>
```

but it didn't work. Anyone can help me? very appreciate.